# Need for coloring only on vowel character with perl on linux

Tags: linux, perl

im trying coloring only on vowel character, but i only can change the whole text color with this code, how to coloring only on vowel character?

im trying using `if ($char=='a')` on `for $char(@chars)` but it doesn't change anything

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Term::ANSIColor;
$color;
$reset=color("reset");
do{
open MYFILE, "/home/yusuf/program/file.txt" or die "could not open . . .";
while(<MYFILE>){
    @chars=split //;
    for $char(@chars){
        print $color;
        print "$char";
        print $reset;
    }
}
close MYFILE;
print "\n=====Program mewarnai semua huruf vocal=====\n";
print "1. Red\n";
print "2. Blue\n";
print "3. Green\n";
print "4. Magenta\n";
print "5. White\n";
print "6. Black\n";
print "Input No: "; $input=<STDIN>;
if ( $input==1 ){
    $color=color("red");
}
elsif( $input==2 ){
    $color=color("blue");
}
elsif( $input==3 ){
    $color=color("green");
}
elsif( $input==4 ){
    $color=color("magenta");
}
elsif( $input==5 ){
    $color=color("white");
}
elsif( $input==6 ){
    $color=color("black");
}
}while($input!=7);
```

Comment: Hint : you probably need to `chomp` the input that you get from STDIN before you process it. This will remove the trailing new line that comes with from the standard input. Try adding `chomp $input;` after `$input=<STDIN>;`

Comment: You can also write `chomp($input=<STDIN>);`. You should really use strict and warnings.

Comment: Its like a i u e o

Comment: The input is only for selecting menu

Comment: The text is from file.txt

Comment: I will change my question then, how i can coloring specific character from my text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!!! It would have identified your problem: `==` is for comparing numbers, while strings are compared using `eq`.

```
my @chars = split //;
for my $char (@chars) {
    if ($char eq 'a') {
       print $color;
       print $char;
       print $reset;
    } else {
       print $char;
    }
}
```

You could also use the following:

```
s/a/${color}a$reset/g;
print;
```

This latter version is easier to extend.

```
s/([aeiou])/$color$1$reset/g;
print;
```

Comment: I'll try this later . . .

Comment: where to put this code
s/([aeiou])/\Q$color\E$1\Q$reset\E/g;
print;

Comment: Anywhere you want to modify `$_` then print it. Note there was a bug in my code that I've fixed (Those `\Q..\E` shouldn't be there. You need those when interpolating into the *pattern* portion of the substitution operator.)